# HTML email "opens" not being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, outlook

**Update**

This question has gotten off on the wrong foot.  Let me pose the question as follows:

Let's say I wanted to show my StackOverflow "flair" badge in the signature of an email in Outlook.  Obviously, I would want the image to be refreshed whenever I reply to an email or forward the email.  Now, assuming the I (and others) have decided to allow images to be downloaded from me (who in this case we'll call a "trusted source") then they would see my flair badge refreshed on subsequent loads.  If I copy and paste this badge into a new email then the image will not refresh on subsequent page loads because Outlook has embedded the image and severed the link to original image.

I completely understand everyone's comments about spam but this question is more about Outlook VML and manipulation of it.  If the answer is always and forever "spam! Off with his head!" then that's fine.  I get it but it seems to me that there may be situations where someone may not want the default behavior of Outlook to modify an email that it has already accepted.

**Original Questions**

We have an internal mail system that dynamically generates and sends HTML emails. We have a web beacon generated by an HTTP handler.  The system works as expected: users recieve emails and we track opens as the web beacon is called.

The problem occurs when someone takes that same email that they just received (and we just tracked) and copies & pastes the content (including the web beacon) into a new email in Outlook.  Outlook embeds all images instead of maintaining the URL back to the web beacon.

Is there a way to generate an image through an HTTP handler such that the src of the image is maintained when pasted in Outlook?

Comment: This is the typical behavior of spammers and spam operators. Luckly, mail readers all over the planet are tacking the necessary measures to protect the privacy of their users, including blocking malware, spyware and spamware as yours.

Comment: Users are always going to be able to get around web beacons; by not loading images by default for instance.

Comment: This is for an internal email system and we aren't interested in tracking users that don't wish to be tracked.  As the question states, the tracking isn't the problem.  Outlook changes the src of the images.  If we avoid discussions about spam for a moment, how can the src of the image be maintained when pasted in Outlook?  Remember, this is for users that are allowing downloading of images.

Comment: Your answer remains 'no'. That's how Outlook works.

Comment: Lets consider for a moment that an intranet product needs to use this spammer's delight technique. If such knob would exist in Outlook, your product would require your users to turn the protection against 'beacons' off, therefore exposing them to the 'real' spammers, wouldn't it? Therefore such product should be considered just as bad as the spam techniques it enables.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is not; That's how Outlook works.

Not only that, your use of "web beacons" is the primary reason that I and many others have our e-mail clients configured not to load external images *at all* except from trusted senders.

Comment: Maybe so but had you already configured Outlook to consider me as a trusted source, would you not expect that Outlook should continue to honor that?

Comment: That's a totally different question, best addressed to Microsoft. The fact remains; the behavior you see is what you get.